# Bulk Insert (TSQL) from csv file with missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

**Problem:**

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE BestTableEver 
    (
    Id INT,
    knownValue INT,
    unknownValue INT DEFAULT 0,
    totalValue INT DEFAULT 0);
```

And I have this CSV File (Loki.csv)

```
Id, knownValue, unknownValue, totalValue 
1, 11114
2, 11135
3, 11235
```

I want to do a bulk insert into the table and since I do not know the values of unknownValue and totalValue yet , I want them to be take up the default value (as defined in the table creation)

**My approach so far**

```
create procedure populateLikeABoss
@i_filepath NVARCHAR(2048)
DECLARE @thor nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @thor=
        'BULK INSERT populateLikeABoss
        FROM ' + char(39) + @i_filepath + char(39) +
        'WITH
        (
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
            ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
            FIRSTROW = 2,
            KEEPNULLS
        )'
    exec(@thor)
END
```

and calling the procedure to do the magic

```
populateLikeABoss 'C:\Loki.csv'
```

**Error**

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
>   for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 2 (sizeOnMedia).

**References**

Keeping NULL value with bulk insert

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187887.aspx)

Similar question without the answer I need

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594072/importing-a-csv-file-using-bulk-insert-command-into-sql-server-table)

Comment: I think the csv is not in the expected format. For keeping null the records should be 1, 11114,, in each row. Other option is to remove the last two columns in header.

Comment: I am omitting the header with FIRSTROW = 2.
But the ','s did the trick. I feel silly now. Thanks

Comment: @KiranHegde You should post it as an answer since it solved the OP's  question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the csv is not in the expected format. For keeping null the records should be in the format `1, 11114,,` in each row. Other option is to remove the last two columns in header.