# BULK INSERT with FIELDTERMINATOR inside field not working

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm trying to load CSV file with BULK INSERT command. But it fails if `FIELDTERMINATOR` is a part of text, for instance:

```
678,"Value with , inside",199
```

Is there a way to make BULK INSERT work with this kind of data?

Comment: get a pipe-delimited file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Bulk insert of CSV file with inconsistent quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782353/sql-server-bulk-insert-of-csv-file-with-inconsistent-quotes)

Comment: If all your rows have quotes like that, you could probably have a suitable separator, but I guess you have the same problem as that question

Comment: If it's not too large of a file, you could open the csv with Excel, save it as an xls/xlsx file, then import it via OPENROWSET.  This won't be too helpful if you need to repeat the process for automation, though.