# Save XLSX as CSV and add consistent encapsulation

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv

I'm running into issues loading a file that doesn't consistently encapsulate address fields.

For example, an XLSX file has the following data (the {tab} represents an actual tab character):

| Name | Address_1 | Address_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 123 St. | Apt A |
| Joe | 123 St. | Apt, B |
| David | 123 St. | Apt{tab}C |

When saved as CSV and opened in notepad, the result is:

```
Name,Address_1,Address_2  
Mary,123 St.,Apt A  
Joe,123 St.,"Apt, B"  
David,123 St.,"Apt{tab}C"
```

Per this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782353/sql-server-bulk-insert-of-csv-file-with-inconsistent-quotes), it is apparently not possible to load this as is. Either none of the values in a single field are encapsulated or all of them must be.

What methods are there to save this XLSX as a CSV and *enforce* encapsulation?

Comment: What do you mean by **load this**? I have no problem either opening or importing it into Excel (or Power Query) as is, with only some fields being quoted. You've only tagged `excel`, `csv`, `export-to-csv`. If you need to quote **all** fields to use in a different program, you can write a VBA routine to format the file as you wish. Look at [Procedure to export a text file with both comma and quote delimiters in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/excel/export-text-file-with-comma-quote).

Comment: There is further discussion of this with additional methods on SuperUser:  [How do you force excel to quote all columns of a CSV file?](https://superuser.com/questions/130592/how-do-you-force-excel-to-quote-all-columns-of-a-csv-file)