# SQL Bulk import

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple bulk import script which is working fine

```
BULK
INSERT tablename
FROM 'd:\www\ftp\test.csv'
  WITH
  (
  KEEPIDENTITY,
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
  ERRORFILE = 'd:\www\ftp\test7.log' 
  )
GO
```

Now in the test.csv file there are values like:

```
Bike, Red, "100,00", Blue
Step, Blue, "60,40", Black
```

My question is how can I handle the "100,00" ("xxx,xx") value in the script?

Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902110/bulk-insert-correctly-quoted-csv-file-in-sql-server

Comment: okay so it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the records into a Temp Table and then do something like this.. to get the result and then you can add the rows into you desired Table.This is your CSV File

[image: CSV_FILE]

Your can do the following to insert it into a temp table .

```
Create Table #Temp
(
Product NVARCHAR(50),
Colour NVARCHAR(50),
Number NVARCHAR(50),
Spare NVARCHAR(50),
Colour1 NVARCHAR(50)
)
GO

BULK
INSERT #Temp
FROM 'C:\Users\ali\Desktop\test.csv'
  WITH
  (
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
  )
GO

UPDATE #Temp
SET Number = Number + ',' + Spare

ALTER TABLE #temp
DROP Column Spare

UPDATE #Temp
SET Number = REPLACE(Number, '"', '') 

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

**Result Set**

[image]

```
SELECT * INTO [Destination_Table] FROM #Temp
DROP TABLE #Temp
```