# How to identify double quotes in only few rows in bulk insert

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I have to bulk insert a file , it's a large file and only 4 rows have `""` in the first column, so I just want to read them. Any ideas? So for those 4 rows I have to insert all data inside the `""` marks into the first column.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes bulk insert , but even with format file , only 4 rows has it , bcp eliminate these rows , is thir a way in bcp for text qualifier

Comment: So you only want to insert text that has `"some text here"` format, and ignore the rest?

Comment: This seems to touch on the same issue (Delimiters present inside string encapsulated record and Bulk Insert): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902110/bulk-insert-correctly-quoted-csv-file-in-sql-server

Comment: @serben no serban , i need all data , but for "" i need every thing in 1 field , so my file is pipe delimited , and in "N|A" in double quotes , so i want to put N|A in one field