# Inserting bulk CSV files into the one SQL table [SQL Server 2008]

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, bulkinsert

I have multiple folders (six or so) with multiple .CSV files in them.  The CSV files are all of the same format:

```
Heading1,Heading2,Heading3
1,Monday,2.45
2,Monday,3.765...
```

Each .CSV has the same heading names [same data source for different months].  What is the best way to import these CSVs into SQL Server 2008?  The server does not have xpShell configured [for security reasons which I cannot modify], so any method which uses that (which I originally tried), will not work.

**EDIT**

The CSV files are a maximum of 2mb in size and do not contain any commas (other than those required for delimiters).

Any ideas?

Comment: How big are the CSV files? You could hypothetically use Excel if you needed to. Note that `BULK INSERT` does not provide a true CSV parser: it does not support escaped quotes, or even commas in quoted values ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902110/bulk-insert-correctly-quoted-csv-file-in-sql-server ) for example.

Comment: The largest CSV file would be around 2mb in size.  The data does not contain any commas or escaped quotes.

Comment: Basically three options - first see if BULK INSERT works for your files as suggested. If not you may need to use SSIS or you could use an external process (like a powershell script) to push the data in.

Answer (score 0):

F.e. you got CSV file names `sample.csv` on `D:\` drive, with this inside:

```
Heading1,Heading2,Heading3
1,Monday,2.45
2,Monday,3.765
```

Then you can use this query:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max),
        @x xml,
        @head xml,
        @sql nvarchar(max),
        @params nvarchar(max) = '@x xml'

SELECT @str = BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK N'D:\sample.csv', SINGLE_CLOB) AS a

SELECT @head = CAST('<row><s>'+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@str,1,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@str)-1),',','</s><s>')+'</s></row>' as xml)

SELECT @x  = CAST('<row><s>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),@str)+1,LEN(@str)),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'</s></row><row><s>'),',','</s><s>')+'</s></row>' as xml)

SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT  t.c.value(''s[1]'',''int'') '+QUOTENAME(t.c.value('s[1]','nvarchar(max)'))+',
        t.c.value(''s[2]'',''nvarchar(max)'') '+QUOTENAME(t.c.value('s[2]','nvarchar(max)'))+',
        t.c.value(''s[3]'',''decimal(15,7)'') '+QUOTENAME(t.c.value('s[3]','nvarchar(max)'))+'
FROM @x.nodes(''/row'') as t(c)'
FROM @head.nodes('/row') as t(c)
```

To get output like:

```
Heading1    Heading2    Heading3
1           Monday      2.4500000
2           Monday      3.7650000
```

At first we take data as `SINGLE_CLOB` with the help of [OPEROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).

Then we put all in `@str` variable. The part from beginning to first `\r\n` we put in `@head`, the other part in `@x` with conversion to XML. Structure:

```
<row>
  <s>Heading1</s>
  <s>Heading2</s>
  <s>Heading3</s>
</row>

<row>
  <s>1</s>
  <s>Monday</s>
  <s>2.45</s>
</row>
<row>
  <s>2</s>
  <s>Monday</s>
  <s>3.765</s>
</row>
```

After that we build dynamic query like:

```
SELECT  t.c.value('s[1]','int') [Heading1],
        t.c.value('s[2]','nvarchar(max)') [Heading2],
        t.c.value('s[3]','decimal(15,7)') [Heading3]
FROM @x.nodes('/row') as t(c)
```

And execute it. Variable `@x` is passing as parameter.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem using a non-SQL answer.  Thank you everyone who helped contribute.  I apologise for going with a completely off-field answer using PHP.  Here is what I created to solve this problem:

```
<?php
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                                                              //
    //      Date:           21/10/2016.                                                             //
    //      Description:    Insert CSV rows into pre-created SQL table with same column structure.  //
    //      Notes:          -  PHP script needs server to execute.                                  //
    //                      -  Can run line by line ('INSERT') or bulk ('BULK INSERT').             //
    //                          - 'Bulk Insert' needs bulk insert user permissions.                 //
    //                                                                                              //
    //      Currently only works under the following file structure:                                //
    //          | ROOT FOLDER                                                                       //
    //                      |   FOLDER 1                                                            //
    //                              |   CSV 1                                                       //
    //                              |   CSV 2...                                                    //
    //                      |   FOLDER 2                                                            //
    //                              |   CSV 1                                                       //
    //                              |   CSV 2...                                                    //
    //                      |   FOLDER 3...                                                         //
    //                              |   CSV 1                                                       //
    //                              |   CSV 2...                                                    //
    //                                                                                              //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Error log - must have folder pre-created to work
    ini_set("error_log", "phplog/bulkinsertCSV.php.log");

    //Set the name of the root directory here (Where the folder's of CSVs are)
    $rootPath = '\\\networkserver\folder\rootfolderwithCSVs';

    //Get an array with the folder names located at the root directory location
    //  The '0' is alphabetical ascending, '1' is descending.
    $rootArray = scandir($rootPath, 0);

    //Set Database Connection Details
    $myServer = "SERVER";
    $myUser = "USER";
    $myPass = "PASSWORD";
    $myDB = "DATABASE";

    //Create connection to the database
    $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB;", $myUser, $myPass) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

    //Extend Database Connection timeout
    set_time_limit(10000);

    //Set to true for bulk insert, set to false for line by line insert
    //  [If set to TRUE] - MUST HAVE BULK INSERT PERMISSIONS TO WORK
    $bulkinsert = true;

    //For loop that goes through the folders and finds CSV files
    loopThroughAllCSVs($rootArray, $rootPath);

    //Once procedure finishes, close the connection
    odbc_close($connection);

    function loopThroughAllCSVs($folderArray, $root){
        $fileFormat = '.csv';
        for($x = 2; $x < sizeof($folderArray); $x++){
            $eachFileinFolder = scandir($root."\\".$folderArray[$x]);
            for($y = 0; $y < sizeof($eachFileinFolder); $y++){
                $fullCSV_path = $root."\\".$folderArray[$x]."\\".$eachFileinFolder[$y];
                if(substr_compare($fullCSV_path, $fileFormat, strlen($fullCSV_path)-strlen($fileFormat), strlen($fileFormat)) === 0){
                    parseCSV($fullCSV_path);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function parseCSV($path){
        print_r($path);
        print("<br>");
        if($GLOBALS['bulkinsert'] === false){
            $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($path));
            array_shift($csv);                              //Remove Headers

            foreach ($csv as $line){
                writeLinetoDB($line);
            }
        }
        else{
            bulkInserttoDB($path);
        }
    }

    function writeLinetoDB($line){
        $tablename = "[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE]";
        $insert = "INSERT INTO ".$tablename." (Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7)
                VALUES ('".$line[0]."','".$line[1]."','".$line[2]."','".$line[3]."','".$line[4]."','".$line[5]."','".$line[6]."')";

        $result = odbc_prepare($GLOBALS['connection'], $insert);
        odbc_execute($result)or die(odbc_error($connection));   
    }

    function bulkInserttoDB($csvPath){
        $tablename = "[DATABASE].[dbo].[TABLE]";
        $insert = "BULK
                    INSERT ".$tablename."
                    FROM '".$csvPath."'
                    WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n')";

        print_r($insert);
        print_r("<br>");

        $result = odbc_prepare($GLOBALS['connection'], $insert);
        odbc_execute($result)or die(odbc_error($connection));
    }
?>
```

I ended up using the script above to write to the database line by line... This was going to take hours.  I modified to the script to use BULK INSERT which unfortunately we didn't have 'permissions' to use.  Once I 'obtained' permissions, the BULK INSERT method worked a charm.