# BULK INSERT from CSV into SQL Server causes error

Tags: sql-server, csv, import

I've got the simple table in CSV format:

```
999,"01/01/2001","01/01/2001","7777777","company","channel","01/01/2001"
990,"01/01/2001","01/01/2001","767676","hhh","tender","01/01/2001"
3838,"01/01/2001","01/01/2001","888","jhkh","jhkjh","01/01/2001"
08987,"01/01/2001","01/01/2001","888888","hkjhjkhv","jhgjh","01/01/2001"
8987,"01/01/2001","01/01/2001","9999","jghg","hjghg","01/01/2001"
jhkjhj,"01/01/2001","01/01/2001","9999","01.01.2001","hjhh","01/01/2001"
090009,"","","77777","","","01/01/2001"
980989,"01/01/2001","01/01/2001","888","","jhkh","01/01/2001"
0000,"01/01/2001","01/01/2001","99999","jhjh","","01/01/2001"
92929,"01/01/2001","01/01/2001","222","","","01/01/2001"
```

I'm trying to import that data into SQL Server using `BULK INSERT` (Transact-SQL)

```
set dateformat DMY;

BULK INSERT Oracleload
FROM '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\Test\T_DOGOVOR.csv'
WITH
    (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
     KEEPNULLS);
```

On the output I get the next error:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 2 (date_begin)....

Something wrong with date format maybe. But what script I need to write to fix that error?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`BULK INSERT` (nor bcp) cannot (properly) handle CSV files, [specially if they have (correctly) `"` quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902110/bulk-insert-correctly-quoted-csv-file-in-sql-server). Alternatives are SSIS or [PowerShell](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/fast-csv-import-in-powershell-to-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

I always look at the data in Notepad++ to see if there are some weird characters, or non-printable characters, like a line break or something.  For this, it seems like you can open it using Notepad (if you don't have Notepad++) do a find-replace for " to nothing...  Save the file, and re-do the Bulk Load.

Answer (score 0):

This record:

> jhkjhj,"01/01/2001","01/01/2001","9999","01.01.2001","hjhh","01/01/2001"

The first column has a numeric type of some kind. You can't put the `jhkjhj` value into that field.

Additionally, some records have empty values (`""`) in date fields. These are likely to be to interpreted as empty strings, rather than `null` dates, and not convert properly.

But the error refers to "row 1, column 2". That's this value:

> "01/01/2001"

Again, the import is interpreting this as a string, rather than a date. I suspect it's trying to import the quotes (`"`) instead of just using them as separators.

You might try bulk loading to a special holding table, and then re-importing from there. Alternatively, you can change how data is exported or write a program to pre-clean it — strip the quotes from fields that shouldn't have them, isolate records that have data that won't insert to an exception file and report.